# How to set the popularity of a product to 100 automatically on creation

Tags: product, category, catalog, position

At the moment I have a category of say 20 products and I have popularity on them all (they are all in a set order)
If I then add a new product to this category, it sets the popularity of this new product to 0.
I want to default the popularity of new products to 100.

How can I do this?

Comment: By *popularity* you mean **position**?

Comment: Yes I do mean position

Answer (score 1):

The perfect solution for this is to develop an [Event-Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) module using the `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_save` event which is fired on product save. Your `Observer.php` will then update the product's `popularity`, like this:

`app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
...
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_save>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updatePopularity</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_save>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

And then in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php`:

```
public function updatePopularity($observer){
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $product->setPopularity(100);
    $product->save();
}
```

Then you should be all set.

Comment: Brilliant! I'll give that a go

Comment: Otherwise, you could go the non-programmatic route and just set the attribute `popularity` to have a default value of 100. You can do this via `Catalog` → `Attributes` → `Manage Attributes`

Comment: I can't access $product

Comment: If I print_r $product its null. So can't setPopularity()
Any ideas?

Comment: Code is working 100% for me. If you say that Magento is reading your Observer.php code, that means that the event listener is set up correctly. Re check the code above & make sure there are no typos on your side.

Comment: I'm getting a fatal error on setPopularity 
Fatal error: Call to a member function setPopularity() on a non-object in

Appriciate the help on this by the way

Comment: you need to listen to this event instead, I have edited the answer:
catalog_product_prepare_save

Comment: I've edited it back to the previous event as there is no benefit of using the one @Behnam suggested, this event is fired when adminhtml processes a product save. In future, give a reason for a suggestion and don't recommend an edit unless there is solid reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Adi, you haven't set up your module correctly. Read the article I posted, you need an event-observer architecture, I.E the only files required in your module folder are `config.xml`, `Observer.php` & `Helper.php`.

Comment: Minus the `Helper.php` :)

Comment: Still having problems with this. 
The event is firing and I can print the event and get some info (see below), but as soon as I try to access ->getProduct() I'm getting null returned.

I've checked the code many times and everything it correct.
Can you please advise.
Below is the var_dump of $observer->getEvent()

Comment: This event will give you the `$action = $observer->getControllerAction();` and maybe from this you can get the product but I am not sure. You can 100% get the request from that.